# Can I hide one GET parameter from more? (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, get

**My original link is:**

```
?action=viewArticle&categoryName=$1&articleId=$2&articleTitle=$3
```

**Modified it with .htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)/([^.]+)$ ?action=viewArticle&categoryName=$1&articleId=$2&articleTitle=$3 [L]
```

**I got this:**

eg.:

```
/News/17/News_title
```

**BUT I don't want to show the article id. I wanna see something like this:**

```
/News/News_title
```

HELP ME PLEASE! :)

Comment: How will you query the database for the correct article? By `News_title`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ ?action=viewArticle&categoryName=$1&articleTitle=$2 [L]
```

should do the trick. However you will need to make sure your titles are unique now